# What is the "apply()" function in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I know this is a silly question but I have seen in a lot of places the below statement:

```
something.apply(this, arguments)
```

Can someone please explain me the use of this function or point me to some kind of documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply() is method of javascript Function.

See the documentation of [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). This a very good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Many components are subclasses of other UI5 components. In SAPUI5, the `apply` method is usually used to call methods in the parent of a subclass. This is often done from methods that override their parents original methods, to make sure that e.g. variables in the parent class are still properly initialised.