# Prototype & Extend in SAPUI5 (Component.js)

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I was trying to implement Component.js in my SAPUI5 application but unable to understand **.extend & .prototype.init.apply method** in below piece of code.

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/UIComponent"
], function (UIComponent) {
    "use strict";
    return UIComponent.extend(""** , {**
        init: function () {
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
            // console.log(UIComponent.extend);
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone please explain?

P.S. I am beginner to OO Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they're doing here is very Java-ish. With `extend` they're creating a subclass of `UIComponent`.

In this subclass the `init` method is overridden. When you override a method of the parent object, it's a good practice to call the parents original method from the method that overrides it. By doing so, you're avoiding unexpected situations such as variables that have not been defined at the parent etc. Calling the parent's original method is exactly what the `init.apply` statement is doing. It's doesn't make sense to me to do this twice though.

Answer (score 2):

To give you some hints:

1. [**extend**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) comes from from [sap.ui.base.Object](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Object.js#L164) which delegates to [sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.createClass()](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Metadata.js#L301). Thanks to [@schnoedel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5477321/schnoedel) to point it out.
2. [**prototype.init.apply**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521284/what-is-apply-function-in-sap-ui5) and [**arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

Comment: I think that hints are best given as a comment, not an actual answer

Comment: extend does actually not come from jquery but from [sap.ui.base.Object](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Object.js#L164) which delegates to [sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.createClass()](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Metadata.js#L301) which does the whole prototype inheritance stuff, creates the properties, associations, aggregations and events from the metadata and much more.

Comment: @schnoedel I just checked and you are right. Thanks a lot. I will edit my answer.